# Node Red - Lost Connection after redirection from port 1880 to a subdirectory

Tags: apache, centos, node-red

I have **NodeRed** installed on a VM with **Cent OS 7.x** and **Apache 2.4.6 (CentOS).**

If I open up the URL `http://10.1.1.1:1880/` , everything is working.  I can deploy nodes and see the debug. But I need Node Red on a special location. 
Next step was the configuration of a Proxy Pass in my httpd.conf .

Result: Node Red is available under `http://10.1.1.1/nr/` . But after a few seconds I got the following error message.

```
Lost connection to server, reconnecting in 44s. Try now
```

Then I tried the same, also adding the port config to the 443, 
Result:  Node Red is available under`https://10.1.1.1/nr/` and it is working for a few seconds. Then the same error message ( + or – a few seconds) appear

```
Lost connection to server, reconnecting in 54s. Try now
```

Then I checked the Console in the Browser
Error Code:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://10.1.1.1/nr/comms' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 a @ red.min.js:16
```

OK, it seems that this is a problem with the WebSocket.
If someone have an idea, great because I tried different solutions added the Load Modules and have at the moment not really an idea. All the best.

ps: This is my proxy pass setting in the httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 10.1.1.1
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
  RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:1880/$1 [P,L]
  ProxyPass /nr/ http://127.0.0.1:1880/ timeout=360
  ProxyPassReverse /nr/ http://127.0.0.1:1880/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Edit  the question with the proxy pass settings you have in your apache config. This is most likely because you have not enabled WebSocket proxying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `RewriteRule` is doing, but I think you need to be using the [mod_proxy_wstunnel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) module and a `ProxyPass` rule like this:

```
ProxyPass "/nr/comms"  "ws://localhost:1880/comms"
```

Comment: Removed the Quotation marks , added the Proxy Pass in the httpd, removed the RewriteEngine , saved, restarted the service and well. it worked. thanks

Answer (score 5):

I did it like this:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass               "/comms"        "ws://localhost:1880/comms"
ProxyPassReverse        "/comms"        "ws://localhost:1880/comms"
ProxyPass               "/"             "http://127.0.0.1:1880/"
ProxyPassReverse        "/"             "http://127.0.0.1:1880/"

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

This solved the issue for me. If you have TLS enabled change ws: to wss:

Comment: Thanks for this.  I didn't need the quotes and used `<Location />Require all granted</Location>` for Apache 2.4 with the `ProxyPass*` outside of the `<Location>` as you have.  I have TLS terminated at Apache but then `http://` and `ws://` to the local service.  Using `http://` and `wss://` (mismatched) got me `500` errors.

Answer (score 0):

With Node-Red 1.0 if used this configuration

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
RewriteRule .* "ws://localhost:1880%{REQUEST_URI}" [P]

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://localhost:1880/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:1880/
```

Using Rewrite engine makes websocket to work correcly. Meanwhile I've not got it to work if I use /nodered/ url instad of /